# Редактор информации в Яндекс.Картах

Tags: javascript, python, веб-программирование, парсер, selenium

Каким способом можно автоматизировать редактирование вкладки в яндекс.картах
[image: Поле сайт в яндекс.карты]

надо сделать проверку уже имеющейся инфы, а если она не соответствует образу изменить ее на нужную.